# I would like to make a method that shows/hides forms based on parameters

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my code so far:

```
TickTock frmTick = new TickTock();
frmTick.Show();
frmTick.Activate();
this.Hide();
```

Basically, I want to change the code above, so that I can use parameters to determine the `Form`s that are shown/hidden.

Something like;

```
static void changeForm(object form, string i)
{
  form i = new form()
  i.show
}
```

Comment: So what is your particular question?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what part of this is causing you trouble, but the simplest way to write such a method would look like this:

```
public void SwitchTo<T>() where T : Form, new()
{
    var form = new T();
    form.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

If you need to be able to implement this method outside of the form that is to be closed (meaning that the line `this.Hide()` wouldn't work), you can [iterate all open forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108368/find-the-open-forms-in-c-sharp-windows-application) and close them first:

```
public void SwitchTo<T>() where T : Form, new()
{
    foreach (var f in Application.OpenForms) f.Hide();
    var form = new T();
    form.Show();
}
```

And you'd call it with:

```
SwitchTo<TickTock>();
```